# Can someone explain why this way of iterating a nested data structure does work?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I wanted to create this array

```
["studies", "theory", "form", "animal", "basic", "processes"]
```

from the following nested data structure (stored as `sorted_hash`):

```
[["studies", {:freq=>11, :cap_freq=>0, :value=>11}],
 ["theory", {:freq=>9, :cap_freq=>1, :value=>11}],
 ["form", {:freq=>9, :cap_freq=>1, :value=>11}],
 ["animal", {:freq=>12, :cap_freq=>0, :value=>12}],
 ["basic", {:freq=>10, :cap_freq=>1, :value=>12}],
 ["processes", {:freq=>13, :cap_freq=>0, :value=>13}]]
```

I confused this to be a hash and wrote the following code to achieve my task:

```
sorted_hash.each do |key,value|
  array.push key
end
```

And I really got what I wanted. But after some thinking and playing around in Pry I wonder why. The `each` method [Ruby Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-each) for Arrays only shows examples with one item variable, as in

`each { |item| block } → ary`

but I use two variables as I would do for Hashes. Will Ruby try to match the given item variables, which in this case succeeds as the 2nd level array has a length of 2?
Is it recommendable to do it like that? 
Are there more idiomatic ways to do it?

Comment: Interestingly, `Hash#each` also only yields one item (that's the contract of `each`, after all, it *always* yields *exactly one item*), an array with two items, *exactly* like in your case. Yet somehow, even though the two cases are *identical* you are confused by one and not the other.

Comment: I must admit that I don't understand what you want to say. `hash#each` seems to expect / yield two items: key and value (`each {| key, value | block } → hsh`). That is not identical to `each { |item| block } → ary`, which only seems to yield one item. Of course, my lack of experience and knowledge as developer might be the reason for not understanding your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer follows from the way "parallel assignment" is implemented in Ruby.

As you probably know:

```
a,b,c   = 1,2,3
a #=> 1 
b #=> 2 
c #=> 3 

a,b,c   = [1,2,3]
a #=> 1 
b #=> 2 
c #=> 3 

a,b     = [1,2,3]
a #=> 1 
b #=> 2 

a,*b    = [1,2,3]
a #=> 1 
b #=> [2, 3] 

*a,b    = [1,2,3]
a #=> [1, 2] 
b #=> 3

a,(b,c) = [1,[2,3]]
a #=> 1 
b #=> 2 
c #=> 3 

a,(b,(c,d)) = [1,[2,[3,4]]]
a #=> 1 
b #=> 2 
c #=> 3 
d #=> 4
```

The last two examples employ "disambiguation", which some people prefer to call "decomposition".

Now let's see how that applies to the assignment of values to block variables.

Suppose:

```
arr = [["studies", {:freq=>11, :cap_freq=>0, :value=>11}],
       ["theory",  {:freq=>9,  :cap_freq=>1, :value=>11}]]
```

and we execute:

```
arr.each { |a| p a }
["studies", {:freq=>11, :cap_freq=>0, :value=>11}]
["theory", {:freq=>9, :cap_freq=>1, :value=>11}]
```

Let's look at this more carefully. Define:

```
enum = arr.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["studies",   {:freq=>11, :cap_freq=>0, :value=>11}],
  #                  ["theory",    {:freq=>9,  :cap_freq=>1, :value=>11}]]:each>
```

The first element is passed to the block and assigned to the block variable `v`:

```
v = enum.next
  #=> ["studies",  {:freq=>11, :cap_freq=>0, :value=>11}]
```

We may be prefer to use parallel assignment with two block variables (after `enum.rewind` to reset the enumerator):

```
a,h = enum.next
a #=> "studies" 
h #=> {:freq=>11, :cap_freq=>0, :value=>11}
```

That allows us to write (for example):

```
arr.each { |a,h| p h }
{:freq=>11, :cap_freq=>0, :value=>11}
{:freq=>9, :cap_freq=>1, :value=>11}
```

Here we do not use the block variable `a`. When that is the case, we might replace it with the local variable `_` or possibly `_a`:

```
arr.each { |_,h| p h }
arr.each { |_a,h| p h }
```

This draws attention to the fact that `a` is not used and may help to avoid errors. Regarding errors, suppose we want:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]].map { |a,b| puts 1+b }
  #=> [3,5]
```

but inadvertently write:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]].map { |a,b| puts a+b }
  #=> [3,7]
```

which executes just fine (but produces an incorrect result). By contrast,

```
[[1,2],[3,4]].map { |_,b| puts a+b }
  #NameError: undefined local variable or method 'a'
```

tells us there's a problem.

Here's a more elaborate example of what you can do in blocks with parallel assignment and disambiguation. Given:

```
h = { :a=>[1,2], :b=>[3,4] }
```

suppose we wish to obtain:

```
    { :a=>3, :b=>7 }
```

One way is the following:

```
h.each_with_object({}) { |(a,(b,c)),g| g[a] = b+c }
  => {:a=>3, :b=>7}
```

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer, Cary. Very instructive.

Answer (score 2):

That's because Ruby conveniently lets you do this:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]].each {|x,y,z| puts "#{x}#{y}#{z}"}
# 123
# 456
```

So basically, `each` yields an array element to the block, and because Ruby block syntax allows "expanding" array elements to their components by providing a list of arguments, it works.

You can find more tricks with block arguments [here](http://www.paperplanes.de/2012/2/16/fun-with-ruby-block-parameters.html).

And by the way, instead of creating an array yourself and calling `push`, you can simply do the following, since `map` returns an array:

```
sorted_hash.map(&:first)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, AmitA. All questions answered.